# How to run Django context processor

Tags: django

I have "context_processors.py" in entertainment_website package/app

I configured it settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"entertainment_website.context_processors.load_sidebar_vars")
```

I would like to somehow debug/print out values from the context_processors.py. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can print some value just like this:

```
def some_context_processor(request):
    return {'system_name': 'test'}
```

and in your html:

```
{{ system_name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is useful for this. Its template panel shows you all the templates rendered, and the values returned by all the context processors.

Comment: This. More context (small pun intended) makes for easier debugging, and the toolbar gives you a *lot* of context.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging in python in general, just add `import pdb` to the top of the script which you wish to debug and use `pdb.set_trace()` in whichever line you wish to insert a breakpoint.

Run the server and as the control reaches the line containing `pdb.set_trace()` take a look at your development server prompt, you can access all local vars to check what vars hold what value.